# SAML For Java Application Running on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, opensaml

I have a Java Application running on tomcat server. I am storing the user information in mysql table and for authentication using Java Rest service.
Now when I land on ***customer.myapp.com*** I want to check if there is an active session in the browser for ***customer.com***, if so login to my app using that session internally . If no session then redirect the user to ***customer.com*** login portal and after login land in ***customer.myapp.com*** home page.

How can I implement this using SAML . I have gone through the theory parts and got an idea about **SP**(in this case customer.myapp.com) and **IdP**(I assume it will the the customer's login portal customer.com) . I even downloaded the **OpenSAML** jar. I have no idea how the configuration is to be done. In my case I don't have any access to the IDP.

```
public class EMSAMLObjectBuilder {
// Get the builder factory
XMLObjectBuilderFactory builderFactory = Configuration.getBuilderFactory();

// Get the assertion builder based on the assertion element name
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
SAMLObjectBuilder<Assertion> builder = (SAMLObjectBuilder<Assertion>) builderFactory.getBuilder(Assertion.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);

// Create the assertion
Assertion assertion = builder.buildObject();
```

}

This is the only piece of code I could find. Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like a standard use case for the SAML Web Browser Profile. I would suggest reading up on in it. There is a lot of information on the Internet.

Basically the process goes like this.

1. The SP and the IDP exchange metadataXML. This can be done by any means for example email or by publishing the xml on a webserver. This is only done once between a SP and IDP.
2. When the SP wants to authenticate the user, it sends it to the IDP using for example redirect together with a SAML Authentication Request.
3. The IDP authenticates the user.
4. The IDP send the user back to the SP together with a SAML Authentication Response

SAML is a very flexible protocol so the flow above can vary. How the communication is doen is generally closer specified in the metadata.

There are several ways this could be implemented, OpenSAML is one of them. The [OpenSAML official website](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OS30/Home) have some helpful examples.

I write a [blog on OpenSAML](http://blog.samlsecurity.com/search?q=opensaml) with lots of helpful post on the subject. I have also written a book, [A Guide to OpenSAML](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/a-guide-to-opensamlv3.html), that details step by step the implementation of a SAML Web Browser Profile service provider.

Coincidently the sample application in the book runs on embedded tomcat.

Comment: I have read your blog, I think I have read many different things and totally confused right now. Can you please tell me from where I should start ? Currently I have a java based tomcat application running on my localhost which is supposed to be my service provider. Currently I don't have an Idp , but I am thinking of using the same application running on a different machine's tomcat and using a different db. In my service provider login page I will give a redirection to the Idp login with some metadata (if I am right). How to get that metadata and how to let my Idp process the request

Comment: I read the links but it says how it works, doesn't say how I can implement it on my existing application. It's an urgent requirement can anyone help?

Comment: I have updated the answer. As for implementation. These two posts say something about the implementation of step 2 and 4. http://blog.samlsecurity.com/2011/01/redirect-with-authnrequest.html http://blog.samlsecurity.com/2011/02/resolve-artifact-with-opensaml.html. The second is about sending a SAML response using Artifact. In this process the IDP sends a pointer to the SAML response. The SP then resolves it on a SOAP WS call.

Comment: Thanks for the response :), but the blog links you provided seems to be broken

Comment: Oh? I tried them now seems fine. What page are you getting when following them?

Comment: Now its working for me also :| . Not sure what was the problem before

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that you should never directly use libraries like OpenSAML which are really low-level and complicated to master.
If you want to secure your web application with a SAML login process, you should certainly use a security library for that.
Disclaimer: I'm the creator of pac4j, so I can recommend using one of the pac4j implementations: http://www.pac4j.org/implementations.html for SAML: http://www.pac4j.org/docs/clients/saml.html